# Problema con el select2 en un modal

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

Recurro a ustedes, debido a que seguí los tutoriales de como colocar un select2 dentro de un modal. Pues bueno lo hice, pero el problema es el siguiente: El select2 sale reducido o mas pequeño.

**Imagen del Select2 dentro del modal**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Ya cambie el código lo que mire en tutoriales el tabindex: null**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="dataPermisos" tabindex="null" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
```

**Este es el código del select 2 de productos:**

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="id_producto" class="control-label">Producto:</label>
                    <div class="input-group date dpYears" data-date-viewmode="" data-date-format="" data-date="">
                        <select name="id_producto" id="id_producto"class="form-control option_s3">
                        <?php
                            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT id_producto, nom_producto from t_producto");
                            $stmt->execute();
                            foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $r) {
                                echo "<option value='".$r[0]."'>".strtoupper($r[1] )."</option>";  
                            }
                        ?>
                    </select><div class="input-group-append">
                                 <button id="agregarProducto" id="dp-ig" class="btn btn-outline-success" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                </div>
```

**Foto Secundaria**

De que me muestra los productos , no hay problema, solo que el select2 es pequeño 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes unas clases personalizadas dentro de tu código, muéstranos el CSS que está aplicando junto a esos `input-group`. También podrías añadir un estilo _in-line_ a ese div para ver si funciona sólo con CSS, algo como `min-width: 200px;`

Comment: Lo resolviste ??, tengo el mismo problema

Answer (score -1):

Elimina el `tabindex` y, para que sea grande, agrégale un `style="width:100%;"` en el `select` (o en tu css si lo tienes personalizado). Con eso jala:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="dataPermisos" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">

   ...

   <select name="id_producto" id="id_producto"class="form-control option_s3" style="width: 100%">

   ...

</div>
```